# Cross-references and captions not working when using gt in Quarto with Word output

Tags: ms-word, quarto, caption, gt, cross-reference

I have been struggling with this off-and-on for a long time. I keep looking at gt() github, stackoverflow, etc... but just end up more confused. I seem to find posts suggesting gt() is working properly with Word. But when I try it, that does **not** seem to be true.

The issue is that I want to

1. use Quarto,
2. have MS Word output,
3. use gt() to generate tables,
4. be able to cross-reference those tables, and
5. (optional) have or suppress captions.

Below is my qmd file contents:

````
---
title: "Test"
format: docx
---

## Try with gt package 

I want to reference my table (@tbl-test), and either have a caption or suppress the missing caption.


```{r}
#| label: tbl-test
#| tbl-cap: "This is a test caption"

library(gt)

tbl <- 
  gt(
    head(mtcars),
    caption = "This is a caption"
  ) |>
  tab_header(title = "This is a Title")

tbl

```

## Try with kable package 

Does it work to reference (@tbl-iris)?

```{r}
#| label: tbl-iris
#| tbl-cap: "Iris Data"

library(knitr)

kable(head(iris))
```
````

When I run this code, I get the following Word output. Please notice the following:

- cross reference NOT working for gt() but IS working for kable
- (**?caption**) added by gt(). I truncated the output, but kable doesn't do this

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and usual apologies if this has been answered - I searched pretty extensively and couldn't find it).

---

[image: docx output from qmd file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been in your shoes before.
See the hacky solution below, where we using a hidden dummy table:

````
---
title: "Hacky cross-references and captions when using gt in Quarto with Word output"
format: docx
---

I want to reference my table (@tbl-test) and have a caption.

```{r}
#| label: tbl-test
#| tbl-cap: "This is a test caption"
#| message: false
#| echo: false

# hidden dummy table
knitr::kable(x = NULL, 
             format = "html" #, 
             # caption = "This is a test caption {#tbl-test}" # disable 'caption' after version v1.4.404
             )
```

```{r}
#| message: false
#| echo: false
tbl <- 
  gt::gt(head(mtcars)) |>
  gt::tab_header(title = gt::md("This is a Title"),   # title = gt::md("")
                 subtitle = gt::md("This is a Subtitle")) |>
  gt::tab_caption(caption = gt::md("This is a test caption"))

tbl
```

Referencing (@tbl-iris)

```{r}
#| label: tbl-iris
#| tbl-cap: "Iris Data"
#| message: false
#| echo: false
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```

See @tbl-test and @tbl-iris
````

Output:
[image]

Also, see discussion in Quarto[#6838](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/6838) with another hacky solution and the reason why it happens, if interested.

Comment: Quarto team is making effort to make cross-referencing better, see https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6816#discussioncomment-6988717.  Cross-referencing is indeed not working when using {gt} in Quarto with Word output, this is known issue: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/3600. In answer above, a temporary workaround is provided where we create an empty (dummy) table with its own reference/caption - omitting the same for gt table, and placing one above another. It is an old trick and it might help if you need to solve your problem immediately.